# bundle not found in beanstalk image

Tags: docker, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I have a single docker container that I'm trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm unable to get migrations working. When using the following `Dockerfile` locally, I'm able to run `docker exec [image] bundle exec rake db:migrate` to run migrations without problem, but after uploading the image to ECR and running my deployment, my `ebextension` errors out, being unable to find `bundle`, as can be seen at the end of the log. The logs also show that `bundle` is installed and installing packages, though. What am I missing?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24:0.9.27
MAINTAINER openback@gmail.com

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  nodejs \
  tzdata

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# === 3 ====

# By default Nginx clears all environment variables (except TZ). Tell Nginx to
# preserve these variables. See nginx-env.conf.
COPY nginx-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf

# Nginx and Passenger are disabled by default. Enable them (start Nginx/Passenger).
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Expose Nginx HTTP service
EXPOSE 80

# === 4 ===

# Our application should be placed inside /home/app. The image has an app user
# with UID 9999 and home directory /home/app. Our application is supposed to run
# as this user. Even though Docker itself provides some isolation from the host
# OS, running applications without root privileges is good security practice.
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/myapp
WORKDIR /home/app/myapp

# Run Bundle in a cache efficient way. Before copying the whole app, copy just
# the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into the tmp directory and ran bundle install
# from there. If neither file changed, both instructions are cached. Because
# they are cached, subsequent commands—like the bundle install one—remain
# eligible for using the cache. Why? How? See ...
# http://ilikestuffblog.com/2014/01/06/how-to-skip-bundle-install-when-deploying-a-rails-app-to-docker/
COPY app/Gemfile /home/app/myapp/
COPY app/Gemfile.lock /home/app/myapp/
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/myapp
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# === 5 ===

# Adding our web app to the image ... only after bundling do we copy the rest of
# the app into the image.
COPY app /home/app/myapp
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/myapp

# === 6 ===

# Remove the default site. Add a virtual host entry to Nginx which describes
# where our app is, and Passenger will take care of the rest. See nginx.conf.
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf


# Enable insecure SSH when in development mode
RUN if [ "$PASSENGER_APP_ENV" = "development" ]; then rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down; fi
RUN if [ "$PASSENGER_APP_ENV" = "development" ]; then /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh; fi
```

**.ebextensions/01_db_migrate.config**

```
container_commands:
  db_migrate:
    command: bundle exec rake db:migrate
    leader_only: true
```

**eb-activity.log**

```
[2018-01-14T21:10:51.873Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Starting activity...
[2018-01-14T21:14:17.998Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  0.9.27: Pulling from phusion/passenger-ruby24
  [...]
  Step 1 : FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24:0.9.27
   ---> f1736db761ba
  Step 2 : MAINTAINER openback@gmail.com
  ---> Running in dcddb323b1ab
   ---> 34d8ff7058b7
  Removing intermediate container dcddb323b1ab
  Step 3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y   build-essential   nodejs   tzdata
   ---> Running in 1af39b2532c2
  Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
  [...]
  Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7,146 B]
  Fetched 26.6 MB in 13s (1,996 kB/s)
  Reading package lists...
  Reading package lists...
  Building dependency tree...
  Reading state information...
  build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
  nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1).
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    tzdata
  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
  Need to get 166 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 2,857 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2017c-0ubuntu0.16.04 [166 kB]
  ESC[91mdpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
  ESC[0mFetched 166 kB in 0s (231 kB/s)
  Selecting previously unselected package tzdata.
  (Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 55%^M(Reading database ... 60%^M(Reading database ... 65%^M(Reading database ... 70%^M(Reading database ... 75%^M(Reading database ... 80%^M(Reading database ... 85%^M(Reading database ... 90%^M(Reading database ... 95%^M(Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 17457 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2017c-0ubuntu0.16.04_all.deb ...
  Unpacking tzdata (2017c-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
  Setting up tzdata (2017c-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...

  Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
  Local time is now:      Sun Jan 14 21:11:42 UTC 2018.
  Universal Time is now:  Sun Jan 14 21:11:42 UTC 2018.
  Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

   ---> e053efc9754a
  Removing intermediate container 1af39b2532c2
  Step 4 : RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
   ---> Running in 8782ccaa3e8c
   ---> 503b9f167e76
  Removing intermediate container 8782ccaa3e8c
  Step 5 : ENV HOME /root
   ---> Running in 5bf2d12026a5
   ---> 25ffac45422f
  Removing intermediate container 5bf2d12026a5
  Step 6 : CMD /sbin/my_init
   ---> Running in 2f803f206f93
   ---> 5aa04afc6b64
  Removing intermediate container 2f803f206f93
  Step 7 : COPY nginx-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf
   ---> b99cd4eacc70
  Removing intermediate container 5c802eda0143
  Step 8 : RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
   ---> Running in 2345a642a3df
   ---> 4ef9f33afcb3
  Removing intermediate container 2345a642a3df
  Step 9 : EXPOSE 80
   ---> Running in 3220f867b8eb
   ---> 2f9056eb40cf
  Removing intermediate container 3220f867b8eb
  Step 10 : RUN mkdir -p /home/app/myapp
   ---> Running in ac59014fcb80
   ---> aa94da5606c8
  Removing intermediate container ac59014fcb80
  Step 11 : WORKDIR /home/app/myapp
   ---> Running in 47bc5bb22156
   ---> a92ce1ccf8af
  Removing intermediate container 47bc5bb22156
  Step 12 : COPY app/Gemfile /home/app/myapp/
   ---> f26d34889f00
  Removing intermediate container 62d0f23c32f0
  Step 13 : COPY app/Gemfile.lock /home/app/myapp/
   ---> 9c894a82eadc
  Removing intermediate container cdb974da3596
  Step 14 : RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/myapp
   ---> Running in b324a7fca911
   ---> 28316c52ffbe
  Removing intermediate container b324a7fca911
  Step 15 : RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
   ---> Running in 301e2891ec7c
  Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
  1 gem installed
  Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
  installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
  users on this machine.
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
  Using rake 12.0.0
  Fetching i18n 0.8.1
  Using minitest 5.10.1
  Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
  Fetching builder 3.2.3
  Fetching erubi 1.6.0
  Fetching mini_portile2 2.1.0
  Fetching rack 2.0.1
  Fetching nio4r 2.0.0
  Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.2
  Fetching mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
  Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
  Fetching jsonapi-renderer 0.1.2
  Fetching arel 8.0.0
  Fetching bcrypt 3.1.11
  Using bundler 1.16.1
  [...]
  Installing rspec-rails 3.5.2
  Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 81 gems now installed.
  Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
   ---> ceb46d19cdbe
  Removing intermediate container 301e2891ec7c
  Step 16 : COPY app /home/app/myapp
   ---> 37438b355ef1
  Removing intermediate container 472247b188f3
  Step 17 : RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/myapp
   ---> Running in d8f4d671ebfc
   ---> 63107ffadaf0
  Removing intermediate container d8f4d671ebfc
  Step 18 : RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ---> Running in b9c790199ec0
   ---> 28e9a9e2eb47
  Removing intermediate container b9c790199ec0
  Step 19 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf
   ---> ee5f7b4707a9
  Removing intermediate container d9f68c634c63
  Step 20 : RUN if [ "$PASSENGER_APP_ENV" = "development" ]; then rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down; fi
   ---> Running in 3230417a11be
   ---> 76ffc8862b1e
  Removing intermediate container 3230417a11be
  Step 21 : RUN if [ "$PASSENGER_APP_ENV" = "development" ]; then /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh; fi
   ---> Running in 85ed9557eba3
   ---> 16105a75b008
  Removing intermediate container 85ed9557eba3
  Successfully built 16105a75b008
  Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
[2018-01-14T21:14:17.999Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result: Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2018-01-14T21:14:17.999Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-01-14T21:14:18.308Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-01-14T21:14:18.309Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_APPNAME] : Starting activity...
[2018-01-14T21:14:18.543Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_APPNAME/Command db_migrate] : Starting activity...
[2018-01-14T21:14:18.550Z] INFO  [3552]  - [Application deployment app-1d8d-180114_160901@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_APPNAME/Command db_migrate] : Activity execution failed, because: /bin/sh: bundle: command not found (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more searching, I found that I was confused about `container_commands`, as I was confused about Beanstalk in general. Beanstalk spins up docker containers that AWS provides, *inside* of which `docker` is run and your images are used. So `container_commands` runs a command within the AWS container, and not one level deeper, which is my container.

I'm still having problems with running migrations in there, but I'm a lot closer.